# MYSQL Trigger: Update before insert

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, trigger, mysql-5.7

I want to increment the order of every video by one every time a video gets inserted so that the new video takes its place

`UPDATE services SET orders = orders + 1`

This doesn't work, I get this [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39445116/mysql-error-1442-cannot-update-a-table-in-a-trigger-stored-procedure), is there an easy fix? I could fix it in PHP but I'll have to fix it in multiple places and find the buggy code, it's just one-liner code, so much easier if it works as a trigger.

Comment: Missing `NEW.` and/or `OLD.`?

Comment: @RickJames  Yes, This is the correct answer, `for each` doesn't work in mysql 5.7

Comment: When you have troubles with a `TRIGGER`, back off and use, say, a Stored Procedure.  Triggers can't do everything.

Comment: @RickJames you are so correct, I backed off when I started having troubles with this trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You forget that trigger works with ONE record.

You may, of course, do something like

```
CREATE TRIGGER increase_orders
ON services
BEFORE INSERT 
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.orders = ( SELECT 1 + MAX(services.orders)
                   FROM services
                   WHERE services.video_id = NEW.video_id );
```

But when 2 clients would insert a record with the same `video_id` you may obtain duplicated `orders` value. And you can do close to nothing with that problem while using this method.